# How to write in a text widget based on the radiobuton selction tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have rewrote the example shown in this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_radiobutton.htm)!

The code is shown here:

```
from tkinter import *


def sel():
    if var.get()==1:
        area.delete(1.0, END)
        area.insert(END, "Bienvenue")
    elif var.get()==2:
        area.delete(1.0, END)
        area.insert(END, "Welcome")
    else:
        selection = "You selected the option " + str(var.get())
        label.config(text = selection)
        area.delete(1.0, END)
        area.insert(END,selection)

root = Tk()


area = Text(root)
area.pack()


var = IntVar()
R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 1", variable=var, value=1,
                   command=sel)
R1.pack(anchor=W)


R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 2", variable=var, value=2,
                   command=sel)
R2.pack(anchor=W)

R3 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 3", variable=var, value=3,
                  command=sel)
R3.pack(anchor=W)


label = Label(root)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Like this, the code will enter a message in the text widget, following the radiobutton value.
Example: if option1 is chosed, i will have the message "bienvenue" in the text widget.

But when i wanted to put this code in a class object, i couldn't have the same result; here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *



class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   

        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

       m1 = PanedWindow()
       m1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
       """ La fenétre principale"""
       self.parent.title("Agent")
       self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

       area = Text(m1)
       area.pack()

       global var
       var = IntVar()
       R1 = Radiobutton(m1, text="Option 1", variable=var, value=1,
                           command=self.sel(area))
       R1.pack(anchor=W)

       R2 = Radiobutton(m1, text="Option 2", variable=var, value=2,
                           command=self.sel(area))
       R2.pack(anchor=W)

       R3 = Radiobutton(m1, text="Option 3", variable=var, value=3,
                          command=self.sel(area))
       R3.pack(anchor=W)


       label = Label(self)
       label.pack()


    def sel(self,area):
        if var.get()==1:
            area.delete(1.0, END)
            area.insert(END, "Bienvenue")
        elif var.get()==2:
            area.delete(1.0, END)
            area.insert(END, "Welcome")
        else:
            selection = "You selected the option " + str(var.get())
            #label.config(text = selection)
            area.delete(1.0, END)
            area.insert(END,selection)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Example(root)   
    root.mainloop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am not sure what i did wrongly when i used the class object. So could you please help me figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line (and similar for the other two buttons):

```
R2 = Radiobutton(m1, text="Option 2", variable=var, value=2,
                       command=self.sel(area))
```

By doing `command=self.sel(area)`, you set `command` to the *result* of *executing* `self.sel(area)`, which is `None`, instead of the method `self.sel` itself.

Instead, I suggest changing `area` to `self.area` in all of your code and removing the additional parameter from the `sel` method.

```
def initUI(self):
   ...
   self.area = Text(m1)
   ...
   R1 = Radiobutton(m1, text="Option 1", variable=var, value=1,
                       command=self.sel)
   ...

def sel(self):
    if var.get()==1:
        self.area.delete(1.0, END)
        ...
    ...
```